# Pine Script Strategy dont creates orders and Close-Orders when using Prices

Tags: pine-script, tradingview-api

It doesnt matter what i try, it doesnt create any Orders at all, when I try comparing the current price with my target price in the if-clause for exiting my order. I copied serveral code snippets here on stackoverflow and googled it but nothing seems to work for me.

What I want (just for example):

- Close the Order, when the price is 5 % lower than the entry price.
- Close the order, if price is 10 % higher than the entry price.

It works, when i dont use the price in the if-clause, but an other argument like "if buy1 == 3" (3 bars since entry). Then it generates all orders und close-orders.

What do i wrong? I tried everything out (see the commented lines for example).

Thanks a lot in advance!

```
//@version=5
strategy('SuperTrend STRATEGY', overlay=true)
Periods = input(title='ATR Period', defval=10)
src = input(hl2, title='Source')
Multiplier = input.float(title='ATR Multiplier', step=0.1, defval=3.0)
changeATR = input(title='Change ATR Calculation Method ?', defval=true)
showsignals = input(title='Show Buy/Sell Signals ?', defval=false)
highlighting = input(title='Highlighter On/Off ?', defval=true)
barcoloring = input(title='Bar Coloring On/Off ?', defval=true)
atr2 = ta.sma(ta.tr, Periods)
atr = changeATR ? ta.atr(Periods) : atr2
up = src - Multiplier * atr
up1 = nz(up[1], up)
up := close[1] > up1 ? math.max(up, up1) : up
dn = src + Multiplier * atr
dn1 = nz(dn[1], dn)
dn := close[1] < dn1 ? math.min(dn, dn1) : dn
trend = 1
trend := nz(trend[1], trend)
trend := trend == -1 and close > dn1 ? 1 : trend == 1 and close < up1 ? -1 : trend
upPlot = plot(trend == 1 ? up : na, title='Up Trend', style=plot.style_linebr, linewidth=2, color=color.new(color.green, 0))
buySignal = trend == 1 and trend[1] == -1
plotshape(buySignal ? up : na, title='UpTrend Begins', location=location.absolute, style=shape.circle, size=size.tiny, color=color.new(color.green, 0))
plotshape(buySignal and showsignals ? up : na, title='Buy', text='Buy', location=location.absolute, style=shape.labelup, size=size.tiny, color=color.new(color.green, 0), textcolor=color.new(color.white, 0))
dnPlot = plot(trend == 1 ? na : dn, title='Down Trend', style=plot.style_linebr, linewidth=2, color=color.new(color.red, 0))
sellSignal = trend == -1 and trend[1] == 1
plotshape(sellSignal ? dn : na, title='DownTrend Begins', location=location.absolute, style=shape.circle, size=size.tiny, color=color.new(color.red, 0))
plotshape(sellSignal and showsignals ? dn : na, title='Sell', text='Sell', location=location.absolute, style=shape.labeldown, size=size.tiny, color=color.new(color.red, 0), textcolor=color.new(color.white, 0))
mPlot = plot(ohlc4, title='', style=plot.style_circles, linewidth=0)
longFillColor = highlighting ? trend == 1 ? color.green : color.white : color.white
shortFillColor = highlighting ? trend == -1 ? color.red : color.white : color.white
fill(mPlot, upPlot, title='UpTrend Highligter', color=longFillColor, transp=90)
fill(mPlot, dnPlot, title='DownTrend Highligter', color=shortFillColor, transp=90)
FromMonth = input.int(defval=9, title='From Month', minval=1, maxval=12)
FromDay = input.int(defval=1, title='From Day', minval=1, maxval=31)
FromYear = input.int(defval=2018, title='From Year', minval=999)
ToMonth = input.int(defval=1, title='To Month', minval=1, maxval=12)
ToDay = input.int(defval=1, title='To Day', minval=1, maxval=31)
ToYear = input.int(defval=9999, title='To Year', minval=999)
start = timestamp(FromYear, FromMonth, FromDay, 00, 00)
finish = timestamp(ToYear, ToMonth, ToDay, 23, 59)
window() =>
    time >= start and time <= finish ? true : false
longCondition = buySignal

//var float lastEntryPrice = na

if longCondition
    if strategy.opentrades == 0
        strategy.entry('buy', strategy.long, when=window())
        //lastEntryPrice = close

shortCondition = sellSignal
//if (shortCondition)
    //strategy.entry("SELL", strategy.short, when = window())
buy1 = ta.barssince(buySignal)
sell1 = ta.barssince(sellSignal)
color1 = buy1[1] < sell1[1] ? color.green : buy1[1] > sell1[1] ? color.red : na
barcolor(barcoloring ? color1 : na)

// Eingangsparameter
//var float stopLossPct = input(1, title='Stop Loss (%)')  // Stop-Loss als Prozentsatz
//var float takeProfitPct = input(1, title='Take Profit (%)')  // Take-Profit als Prozentsatz

// Stop-Loss-Ebene berechnen
//var float stopLossLevel = strategy.position_avg_price - 1.000  //* (1 - stopLossPct/100)

// Take-Profit-Ebene berechnen
//var float takeProfitLevel = strategy.position_avg_price + 1.000  //* (1 + takeProfitPct/100)


var float slPrice = strategy.position_avg_price * 0.95
var float tpPrice = strategy.position_avg_price * 1.1

// Stop-Loss-Order auslösen, wenn der Preis die Stop-Loss-Ebene erreicht
if close <= slPrice
    strategy.close('buy', comment='SL')

    // Take-Profit-Order auslösen, wenn der Preis die Take-Profit-Ebene erreicht
else if close >= tpPrice
    strategy.close('buy', comment='TP')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var float slPrice = strategy.position_avg_price * 0.95
var float tpPrice = strategy.position_avg_price * 1.1
```

https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-reference/v5/#op_var

For the first bar `strategy.position_avg_price` will be `NaN`, because there is no open position. And `var` variable statement makes it to store this value, until it will not be reassigned.

This will be correct statement in your case:

```
slPrice = strategy.position_avg_price * 0.95
tpPrice = strategy.position_avg_price * 1.1

if close <= slPrice
    strategy.close('buy', comment='SL')

else if close >= tpPrice
    strategy.close('buy', comment='TP')
```